# Collections and Lists

Tags: c#, .net, collections

Is it a pretty safe assumption that the following class is an odd representation of "downgrading" (for lack of a better word) the private class field?

```
public class AggregatedClass : ICollection<SingleClass>
{
    List<SingleClass> _singleClassList;

    // ...rest of code
}
```

I recently saw a "working" example of this, and it threw me for a bit of a loop.  What is the point of the above?  If `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`, then isn't the above class a reversal?  You're having a private class field that's type class is an extension of it's parent's class implementation (`ICollection<T>`).

Is it accurate to say the above example is not really a great design?

Comment: Well, you still need a data structure to hold the data, right? Be it a list, or array, ICollection<T> or whatever. List<T> happens to make it pretty easy to implement ICollection<T>.

Comment: @hawkke "List<T> happens to make it pretty easy to implement IColleciton<T>."  Do you say that just because `List<T>` actually implements ICollection<T>?

Comment: Is it redundant? Sure, a little. You could make an argument that _singleClassList could be a public property. But doing so exposes the entire list, which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This abstracts the `List<T>` as an implementation detail, and ifappropriate / needed the class can now provide additional logic in the various methods of the list (Add/Remove etc; noting that these are non-virtual on List-of-T).

If you mean the field should be ICollection - well, that is up to the class! It might be making use of the additional List-of-T methods, or it could just be an irrelevant implementation detail, that was handy for whoever wrote the class, and does no harm since it is private anyway.

Comment: So what you're basically saying is that the class that implements `ICollection<T>` may need to utilize `List<T>` members, but publically an instance of `AggregatedClass` shouldn't be able to utilize the `List<T>` members?

Comment: @Shark the caller shouldn't care **what** it uses internally as long as it meets the advertised contracts...

Comment: Right, so basically this is a form of security (or...moreso a restriction) to not expose `List<T>` members, and only expose `ICollection<T>` members (at the very least)?

Comment: @Shark not really *security* - just... encapsulation. It is unlikely the caller needs anything else than that, so don't offer it. Allows maximum flexibility to change it as needed.

Answer (score 6):

I would say there is nothing wrong with that. The `AggregatedClass` provides a contract that is `ICollection<SingleClass>` and how that contract is implemented is an implementation detail, no pun intended.

If for the example the class was defined like:

```
public class AggregatedClass : List<SingleClass>
```

then I would have to say that yes, there is a design problem with that. It is recommended to not expose `List<T>` in **public API** and instead expose `Collection<T>` since collection provides virtual methods like `InsertItem` and `ClearItems` and the list counterpart does not provide any virtual methods that can later be used to override behavior in a base class.

If however you don't want to specifically inherit from `Collection<T>` then implementing the `ICollection<T>` like in the example you provided is another suitable alternative, that also allows for the class to inherit from other base class.

Answer (score 3):

It almost depends on what *AggregatedClass* what will do in the near future: by implementing *ICollection* using a private field leave the designer is free to make AggregatedClass derive from another one.

Since C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance, it is a precious thing.

In my opinion, if the class is "mainly" a *List* I would derive it directly. In the case I need to inherit from another class, it's always possible to refactor class in the way you have shown in your question.